# while loops , int vs char reading from scanf , true and false

Tags: c, loops, char, int, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number; // We make 1 int named number
    scanf("%d",&number); // We give to number some number xd
    while (number!=0)// We made a loop while if number isn't 0 do that
    {
        printf("text");// print text
        scanf("%d",&number); // and get again a number. 
        // So everything works well beside inserting some char instead of int.
        // So what is the problem wont scanf return 0 so we exit the program not
        // just printing a text all day?  That's my first question.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second problem is how to make a program reading numbers from keyboard till I enter some special sign for ex '.' Yea we do it with loop while right? But how when `scanf("%d",&something)` it give me back `0` if I enter everything but number?

Comment: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) -- what character makes `number == 0` if you scan as a character instead of a int? (hint: none)? Always, always **validate the return** of any function you use to take user-input (especially `scanf`).

Comment: It doesen't return 0 ? bc its false ?

Comment: When deciding whether to terminate the loop, instead of just looking at the value of `number`, also (or only) look at *the return value of `scanf` itself*.

Comment: The ASCII character `'0'` has decimal value `48`. The character with decimal value zero is the *nul-character* (which you can't enter). What about `while (scanf("%d",&number) == 1) puts ("text");` ?

Comment: Bonus: what remains in `stdin` ***unread*** if you type something other than a number? What type failure does it cause with `scanf`? (*matching* or *input*?) What if you needed to take more input after your loop exited? Spend 45 minutes with [`man 3 scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and save yourself ten-times that number of hours of frustration later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it from scanf int to char

Assumption: You are reading a single char at a time

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = "0";
    int n = 0;

    while (n != 46)// we made a loop while if char isn't '.' ASCII - 46 do that
    {
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        n = (int)c;
        printf("text %d", n);
        //Add if statement to confirm it is a number ASCII 48 - 57 and use it.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Just some more info on how to use numbers:
input number one by one or just a whole number like 123 with some ending special char like ';' or change the line

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

to:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

this way it will register '\n' as ASCII 10

use that with atoi to get the actual int value and use it.

EDIT 2:

@World, you cannot expect to read only numbers and '.'
One way to do this with your own code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = "0";
    int n = 0;
    int number = 0;

    while (n != 46)// we made a loop while if char isn't '.' ASCII - 46 do that
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        n = (int)c;

        if (n>=48 && n<=57) {
            number *= 10;
            number += (n-48);
        }
        if (n==10) {
             printf("text %d\n", number);
             //Use number for something over here
             number = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 3:
Logic behind this:

Let's say you enter 341 in the console
the line

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

will read this one by one thus reading '3', '4', '1' and '\n' respectively
the while loop

```
while (n != 46)
```

will thus run 4 times where:

1st time

c = '3'; 

 n = 51; 

 if (n>=48 && n<=57) is true;

 number = 0 * 10; 

 number = number + n - 48 = 0 + 51 - 48 = 3

2nd time

c = '4'; 

 n = 52; 

 if (n>=48 && n<=57) is true;

 number = 3 * 10 = 30; 

 number = number + n - 48 = 30 + 52 - 48 = 34

3rd time

c = '1'; 

 n = 49; 

 if (n>=48 && n<=57) is true;

 number = 34 * 10 = 340; 

 number = number + n - 48 = 340 + 49 - 48 = 341

4th time

c = '\n'; 

 n = 10; 

 if (n>=48 && n<=57) is false;

 if (n==10) is true;

 it prints "text 341" and sets number to 0

while loop exits when c = '.' and n = 46

Comment: How do I enter `341`?

Comment: '3', '4', '1', '\n', append to string, atoi()

Comment: you can enter 341, scanf will just read it char by char, thus printing out: 
text 51text 52 text 49

Comment: not what i am asking about my question is 
How to get a int from scanf and then work with them like n++ or using if statemans and when i insert ' .'  and only ' . ' not other char only ' . ' to break from while .

Comment: Ok the second code works perfectly but how did it work why we get number *10 and if not n-48 i don't understand .

Comment: scanf will get all the characters which includes the end of line or '\n' character also. n = (int)c; converts a char into it's ASCII value, read about ascii here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII. thus char '0' = 48, '1' = 49, '2' = 50 and so on. I'll add an edit to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

> how to make a program reading numbers from keyboard till I enter some special sign for ex '.'

When `scanf("%d",&number)` returns 0, there is some non-numeric input.  Read that non-numeric input with alternate code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    int number;
    int scan_count = scanf("%d", &number);
    if (scan_count == EOF) break;  // End-of-file or rare input error.
    if (scan_count != 1) {
      int ch = fgetc(stdin);
      if (ch == '.') break;  // Expected non-numeric input to break the loop.
      printf("Unexpected input character '%c'\n", ch);
    } else {
      printf("Expected numeric input: %d\n", ch);
    }
  } // endwhile
  printf("Done\n");
}
```

---

A better approach is to  ditch `scanf()` and use fgets()` to read user input.  Then process the inputted string.